# How to concatenate IIFs in SQL Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif-function

What I am trying to do is to create a table where I have two columns, the second one being a clustering of the Variable1, to categorize it according to its values; if < 0.1, then I want to show "0-10", if the value is between 0.1 and 0.2, then show, "11 - 20", if other, then show "21 - 100". When I run the code below, "Missing syntax operator error" appears.

```
SELECT Variable2_name,
       IIF(Variable1_name< 0.1,
           "0 - 10",
           IIF(Variable1_name >= 0.1 AND Variable1_name < 0.2,
               "11 - 20",
               "21 - 100")
       ) AS Bucket
FROM Table
GROUP BY Variable2_name,
         IIF(Variable1_name < 0.1,
             "0 - 10",
             IIF(Variable1_name < 0.1,
                 "0 - 10",
                 IIF(Variable1_name >= 0.1 AND Variable1_name < 0.2,
                     "11 - 20",
                     "21 - 100")
             ),
ORDER BY Variable2_name
```

The problems has to be within the IIF clause, since when I had a simple IIF clause it worked properly. What is wrong with the syntax? What is the way to write concatenate an IIF clause within another IIF clause, and how do you have to include that in the GROUP BY clause?

Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Take one look at your formatted query and tell us what the problem is.  The `IIF()` calls you make in the `SELECT` look legitimate, but the `GROUP BY` is a mess, with a nested `IIF` in there which appears to just be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an obvious syntax error in the code (two `iif()`s in the `select` and three in the `group by`).  In general, `switch` is easier to work with than nested `iif()`s.  It works a lot like `case` in other databases:

```
SELECT Variable2_name,
       SWITCH(Variable1_name < 0.1, "0 - 10",
              Variable1_name < 0.2, "11 - 20",
              "21 - 100"
             ) AS Bucket
FROM Table
GROUP BY Variable2_name,
         SWITCH(Variable1_name < 0.1, "0 - 10",
                Variable1_name < 0.2, "11 - 20",
                "21 - 100"
               )
ORDER BY Variable2_name;
```

Note:  Because the logic it iterative through the `SWITCH()`, you don't need two parts for the second condition.  This also reduces the chance of errors.

Second, you are not using any `GROUP BY` functions, so you could further simply using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Variable2_name,
       SWITCH(Variable1_name < 0.1, "0 - 10",
              Variable1_name < 0.2, "11 - 20",
              "21 - 100"
             ) AS Bucket
FROM Table
ORDER BY Variable2_name;
```

And, the `DISTINCT` is not necessary if you know that the values are already distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Further to your malformed cut-and-paste, you can reduce it slightly:

```
SELECT Variable2_name,
       IIF(Variable1_name < 0.1,
           "0 - 10",
           IIF(Variable1_name < 0.2,
               "11 - 20",
               "21 - 100")
       ) AS Bucket
FROM Table
GROUP BY Variable2_name,
       IIF(Variable1_name < 0.1,
           "0 - 10",
           IIF(Variable1_name < 0.2,
               "11 - 20",
               "21 - 100")
       )
ORDER BY Variable2_name
```